# how can make a query that get data including same column data and different columns by list in JPQL

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have a question about JPQL. 
It's how to make a jpql which get key data and lists.
Being below a table, I'd like to get data by ReceiptNoProduct ( Grouping by **receipt_no**, and list **product_id**). 
How can I make JPQL?

TABLE ==========

```
Sale
id | receipt_no | product_id
1  | 123        | 1
2  | 123        | 2
3  | 131        | 1
4  | 131        | 4
```

=============================

```
public class ReceiptNoProduct {
    private String receiptNo;
    private Set<Product> products;
}
```

Comment: How does your JPA mappging and the entities look like?

Comment: I got a miss. I'd like to get data without mapping.
The table has more column. I want to project table.